# Selenium find_element(By.XPATH, '') cannot locate the element

Tags: selenium-webdriver, xpath

Here is the website:
https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com/

I tried to login. And I find the username for HTML:

Here is my attempt, but it has the error that the element cannot be located.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

service = Service(r'D:\Softwares\chromedriver.exe')
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com"
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wait until elements are loaded completely. Use selenium's [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/) feature.

**Refer the below code:**

```
url = "https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com"
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='username']"))).send_keys("test")
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

**Result:**

[image]